# Double factorial swi-prolog

Tags: prolog

help please I need to find ((2n-1)!!) \ (2n)!! but I only know how to write factorial not double.

```
factorial(0,1). 
factorial(N,F) :-  
   N>0, 
   N1 is N-1, 
   factorial(N1,F1), 
   F is N * F1.
```

Comment: Is it not (2n)!!/((2n-1)!!) ? Since these values get big really fast, I have a hunch that the true purpose of the assignment is to make a smart implementation - NOT to call `factorial` twice. Note, for example, that (2n)!/((2n-1)!)  = 2n .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up the Wikipedia entry on [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) you can easily spot the two candidates for base cases: 0!! = 1 and 1!! = 1. Depending on the number n being odd or even you'll arrive at one of those base cases when calculating n!! recursively because, in the recursive rule, n is decreased by 2 instead of 1 (compared to n!). You can express that in Prolog like so:

```
doublefactorial(0,1).
doublefactorial(1,1).
doublefactorial(N,F) :-
   N > 1,
   N2 is N-2,
   doublefactorial(N2,F1),
   F is N * F1.
```

If you query this predicate you'll get the desired result:

```
?- doublefactorial(0,F).
F = 1 ;
false.

?- doublefactorial(1,F).
F = 1 ;
false.

?- doublefactorial(2,F).
F = 2 ;
false.

?- doublefactorial(3,F).
F = 3 ;
false.

?- doublefactorial(4,F).
F = 8 ;
false.

?- doublefactorial(5,F).
F = 15 ;
false.
.
.
.
```

However, due to the use of `>/2` and `is/2`, this predicate can only be used in one direction:

```
?- doublefactorial(N,10395).
ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

?- doublefactorial(N,F).
N = 0,
F = 1 ;
N = F, F = 1 ;
ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

If you'd like to use the predicate in all directions you could opt to use CLP(FD):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).  

doublefactorial2(0,1).
doublefactorial2(1,1).
doublefactorial2(N,F) :-
   N #> 1,
   N2 #= N-2,
   F #= N * F1,
   doublefactorial2(N2,F1).

?- doublefactorial2(N,10395).
N = 11 ;
false.

?- doublefactorial2(N,46080).
N = 12 ;
false.

?- doublefactorial2(N,F).
N = 0,
F = 1 ;
N = F, F = 1 ;
N = F, F = 2 ;
N = F, F = 3 ;
N = 4,
F = 8 ;
N = 5,
F = 15 ;
N = 6,
F = 48 ;
N = 7,
F = 105 ;
N = 8,
F = 384 ;
N = 9,
F = 945 ;
.
.
.
```

Note how the goal `F #= N * F1` can now be put in front of the recursive goal, thus making the predicate tail-recursive, because that equation is now propagated as a constraint. For more information see the SWI-Prolog documentation on [CLP(FD)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html).

To calculate (2n)!!/(2n-1)!! or (2n-1)!!/(2n)!! for a particular n you can query the the predicate like this:

```
?- N=5, X #= 2*N, doublefactorial2(X,F1), Y #= 2*N-1, doublefactorial2(Y,F2), RESULT is F1/F2.
N = 5,
X = 10,
F1 = 3840,
Y = 9,
F2 = 945,
RESULT = 4.063492063492063 ;
false.

?- N=5, X #= 2*N, doublefactorial2(X,F1), Y #= 2*N-1, doublefactorial2(Y,F2), RESULT is F2/F1.
N = 5,
X = 10,
F1 = 3840,
Y = 9,
F2 = 945,
RESULT = 0.24609375 ;
false.
```

Note that the result is actually calculated using `is/2`. This is because, in general, the result is not an integer but a rational number, hence you can use CLP(Q) to get the result as a fraction:

```
?- use_module(library(clpq)).
% library(clpq) compiled into clpq 0.08 sec, 1,189 clauses
true.

?- N=5, X #= 2*N, doublefactorial2(X,F1), Y #= 2*N-1, doublefactorial2(Y,F2), {RESULT = F1/F2}.
N = 5,
X = 10,
F1 = 3840,
Y = 9,
F2 = 945,
RESULT = 256 rdiv 63 ;
false.

?- N=5, X #= 2*N, doublefactorial2(X,F1), Y #= 2*N-1, doublefactorial2(Y,F2), {RESULT = F2/F1}.
N = 5,
X = 10,
F1 = 3840,
Y = 9,
F2 = 945,
RESULT = 63 rdiv 256 ;
false.
```

For more details see the SWI-Prolog documentation on [CLP(Q)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpqr). Due to the use of CLP(FD) you can also query for a range of n, say 1 to 5:

```
?- N in 1..5, X #= 2*N, doublefactorial2(X,F1), Y #= 2*N-1, doublefactorial2(Y,F2), {RESULT = F1/F2}.
N = Y, Y = F2, F2 = 1,
X = F1, F1 = RESULT, RESULT = 2 ;
N = 2,
X = 4,
F1 = 8,
Y = F2, F2 = 3,
RESULT = 8 rdiv 3 ;
N = 3,
X = 6,
F1 = 48,
Y = 5,
F2 = 15,
RESULT = 16 rdiv 5 ;
N = 4,
X = 8,
F1 = 384,
Y = 7,
F2 = 105,
RESULT = 128 rdiv 35 ;
N = 5,
X = 10,
F1 = 3840,
Y = 9,
F2 = 945,
RESULT = 256 rdiv 63 ;
false.
```